# How to reduce my application size

Tags: android

I have an application 54 MB in size, of which 53 MB is an mp3 file in my res folder.

Due to the large application size , I am not able to run the application in the emulator. Getting error like   "com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: No space left on device", "INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR]", " the user data image is used by another emulator".

I increased the internal memory of my avd by setting "-partion-size 2047" and sometimes its running but most of time getting I'm getting the same problem.

Is it possible to reduce the mp3 file size?
Is there any another solution? please help.

Comment: Re-encoding the MP3 Files with a lower bitrate will reduce their size

Answer (score 7):

What I see in many games to reduce the initial size is put all the "heavy" data outside the main apk and download it on the first run.

You have an example application of that [here](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Samples/Downloader)

Comment: That is the way my applications handle large content. Works quite well for me. Just make some splashscreen before your real application that waits until the data are downloaded and then start your normally first activity of your application

Answer (score 5):

How about having the application download the mp3 files to SD-card after the application have been installed?

Else, you could try and do some compression on the audio files.

Answer (score 1):

Re-encoding the MP3 Files with a lower bitrate will reduce their size.

Answer (score 1):

you should reduce the size of your MP3 file using a software like MP3 Resizer :downloadable [here](http://www.clubic.com/lancer-le-telechargement-145102-0-mp3resizer.html)